# Is it necessary to remove all file descriptors in the interest list before closing the epoll instance itself?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, operating-system, epoll

Provided that:

- I have created an epoll instance `epfd` by `epoll_create`, and registered many regular file descriptors by `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`.
- I want to close the epoll instance by `close(epfd)`

The [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) does't say whether I must `EPOLL_CTL_DEL` all file descriptors before `close(epfd)`.

So, my question is:

**Is it necessary to remove all file descriptors in the interest list before closing the epoll instance itself?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to manually remove them.

From the [`epoll_create(2)` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_create.2.html) (emphasis added)

> When all file descriptors referring to an epoll instance have been closed, the kernel destroys the instance **and releases the associated resources** for reuse.